# Output the rows with certain initial string of some specific column

Tags: python, csv

I have a tab-delimited txt file like this:

```
A   B   aaaKP
C   D   bbbZ
E   F   cccLL
```

This is tab-delimited.

If

```
phrase = aaa or bbb
column = 3
```

then I would like only those rows whose 3rd column starts with aaa or bbb

The output will be

```
A   B   aaaKP
C   D   bbbZ
```

I have a code for the case where there is only one phrase.

```
phrase, column = 'aaa', 3
fn = lambda l : len(l) >= column and len(l[column-1]) >= len(phrase) and phrase == l[column-1][:len(phrase)]
fp = open('output.txt', 'w')
fp.write(''.join(row for row in open('input.txt') if fn(row.split('\t'))))
fp.close()
```

But if there are multiple phrases.. I tried

```
phrase, column = {'aaa','bbb'}, 3
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general case you can use regular expressions with branches for quick matching and searching:

```
import re

phrases = [ 'aaa', 'bbb' ]
column = 3

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(i) for i in phrases))
column -= 1

with open('input.txt') as inf, open('output.txt', 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        row = line.split('\t')
        if pattern.match(row[column]):
            outf.write(line)
```

The code builds a regular expression from all the possible phrases, using `re.escape` to escape special characters. The resulting expression in this case is `aaa|bbb`. `pattern.match` matches the beginning of the string against the pattern (the match must start from the first character).

However if you **must only match the beginning of string against fixed phrases**, then do note that [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) accepts a tuple, and this is the fastest code:

```
 phrases = [ 'aaa', 'bbb' ]
 column = 3

 phrase_tuple = tuple(phrases)
 column -= 1

 with open('input.txt') as inf, open('output.txt', 'w') as outf:
     for line in inf:
         row = line.split('\t')
         if row[column].startswith(phrase_tuple):
             outf.write(line)
```

Also it demonstrates the use of context managers for opening the file, opens the `input.txt` before `output.txt` so that if the former does not exist, the latter does not get created. And finally shows that this looks nicest without any generators and lambdas.

Comment: @Antti_Haapala Thank you! The first method works. However, the second method yields an error message "list object has no attribute startswith"

Comment: Fixed, `row` -> `row[column]` forgotten to change in code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use python's re module for this,

```
>>> import re
>>> data = """A   B   aaaKP
... C   D   bbbZ
... E   F   cccLL"""
>>> m = re.findall(r'^(?=\S+\s+\S+\s+(?:aaa|bbb)).*$', data, re.M)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
A   B   aaaKP
C   D   bbbZ
```

Positive lookahead is used to check whether the line contains particular string. The above regex checks for the lines in which the third column starts with `aaa` or `bbb` . If yes, then the corresponding lines will be printed.

You could try this regex code also,

```
>>> s = """A    B       aaaKP
... C   D       bbbZ
... E   F       cccLL
... """
>>> m = re.findall(r'^(?=\S+\t\S+\t(?:aaa|bbb)).*$', s, re.M)
>>> for i in m:
...     print i
... 
A   B   aaaKP
C   D   bbbZ
```

Comment: @Avinash_Raj Thank you! But this does not seem to import input.txt and then save the output like as in output.txt. How should it be edited for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import csv
from pprint import pprint


def read_phrases(filename, phrases):
    with open(filename, "r") as fd:
        reader = csv.reader(fd, delimiter="\t")
        for row in reader:
            if any((row[2].startswith(phrase) for phrase in phrases)):
                yield row


pprint(list(read_phrases("foo.txt", ["aaa"])))
pprint(list(read_phrases("foo.txt", ["aaa", "bbb"])))
```

**Example:**

```
$ python foo.py
[['A', 'B', 'aaaKP']]
[['A', 'B', 'aaaKP'], ['C', 'D', 'bbbZ']]
```